# RaspberryPi 4: tftp boot issues with udpsvd / qemu

Tags: embedded, qemu, boot, tftp, initramfs

I build a minimal linux system with buildroot to provide some services like tftp and a other things. From that i want to boot my rpi4 over network with initramfs. Currently i do this from an ubuntu virtual machine, but the footprint is a little bit too large.

The network connection from the host is bridged with a tap0 interface for qemu, so the system is visible in the router. To serve tftp I use 'udpsvd', so, when the qemu system runs, it looks like that:

```
udpsvd -vE 192.168.178.59 69 tftpd /srv/tftp/
```

When trying to manually connect to this tftp server, it works to download files. When booting the PI from that, i receive exactly the same output then doing it on the Ubuntu tftp:

[image]

You may wonder: It claims that start4.elf or recovery.elf is missing, but don't worry, this claims appear also at the ubuntu tftp service, he grabs the start.elf and after about 2 minutes the bootprocess continues.

My problem is, that the qemu variant stucks booting when the bootfiles are downloaded (you can see in the udpsvd log, that something is going on and the files were transfered). My question is, how can I debug this issue? The logs from the PI looks equal in both variants, the qemu tftp is working, the bootfiles are exactly the same. Let me know if you need further informations.